# OpenGL multiple textures, one works, other appears brown

Tags: opengl, textures, shader

I have a program that loads in a background texture, then loads in a model with some materials that may have textures assigned (the loading works fine).

When rendering, it first binds the background texture and renders the background using it's own render calls etc.

Then it renders the models (which involves binding the model textures when a specific material is being rendered, and so on).

Problem: The background shows up fine, but the model is not textured. It is a uniform light brown colour.

Do I need to use multiple texture units?

More info: I'm in the process of converting this program from using the fixed function pipeline to using shaders. Currently the background is rendered the old way, but I'm using shaders to render the model. The reason I'm confused is that if I render the model using the fixed pipeline the textures show up fine, but as soon as I use my shader program then it comes up uniformly brown.

I am setting `glUniform1i(texture_sampler_uniform_location, 0);` after loading the shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after loading the shader **s**

I think that's your problem right there. Uniform values are individual per shader, so you have to specify them for each shader program. The way you formulated your question hints, that you're setting the uniform value only once, expecting it to be shared among all shaders.

Also uniform brown color indicates, that there's no proper texture coordinate applied. How does your vertex and fragment shader code look like, and how do you supply texture coordinates?

Comment: "uniform brown color indicates, that there's no proper texture coordinate applied"

Thanks, cleared up the reason at least. There is only one shader program that uses the uniform, so that wasn't the problem.

I've actually fixed it now, but am not certain how or where I did it. Removed all the glActiveTexture calls and some other duff code.

I think I was initially confused with transparent textures, which led to unnecessary changes which broke the code. Then realised all I had to do was set alpha value to 1.0, but by that time it was broken from the "supposed fixes" -> brown textures. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple textures, then you need to use [`glActiveTexture(GLenum texture)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) as well.

Basically you initialize your shader like you already do, though you need to do it per texture handle.

```
glUniform1i(texture1_sampler_uniform_location, 0);
glUniform1i(texture2_sampler_uniform_location, 1);
```

Then when you want to render and use the texture, you do the following.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1_handle);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2_handle);
```

Comment: I think OP merely wants to switch textures. For that you don't need to use multiple texture units (if that were the case you'd run out of texture units pretty soon).

Comment: @datenwolf I seem to have read it as, OP not being able to use multiple textures, which would imply the need to use `glActiveTexture`.

Comment: OP wrote `Problem: The background shows up fine, but the model is not textured. It is a uniform light brown colour.` – this is not a multitexturing issue, but a texture switching issue.

Comment: It is indeed actually a texture switching issue, sorry for the confusion.